# Entendiendo las relaciones en Laravel (en migraciones y en su ORM Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model, migration

Quisiera aclarar un tema respecto a **Laravel**. Se trata de las **relaciones** tanto a nivel de **migraciones/tablas** (*Claves foraneas*) como a nivel de **Modelo** (ORM *Eloquent*).

Propongo un ejemplo en el cual estoy actualmente trabajando, muy simple. Tenemos **3 tablas** (*Mundos,Clases,Razas*.

**Cardinalidad de relaciones a tener en cuenta**:

**1** *Mundo* tiene **N** *Clases* y, por otro lado, **1** *Mundo* tiene **N** *Razas*

Una vez dicho esto pasemos a las ***dudas***:

Empecemos por las **migraciones**. Voy a poner mi ejemplo basado en las tablas anteriormente citadas:

**Migracion de Mundo**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMundosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mundos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombre')->unique();
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('mundos');
    }
}
```

Bueno, la **tabla mundo** no tiene **foreign key**, así que me limito a crear la migración con sus campos y listo. No hay ni duda ni problema hasta aquí. Continuemos..

**Migración de Clase**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateClasesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clases', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombre')->unique();
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->bigInteger('mundo_id');

            $table->foreign('mundo_id')->references('id')->on('mundos');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('clases');
    }
}
```

**Migración de Raza**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRazasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('razas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombre')->unique();
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->bigInteger('mundo_id');

            $table->foreign('mundo_id')->references('id')->on('mundos');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('razas');
    }
}
```

En las dos últimas **migraciones** (*Migración de Clase* y *Migración de Raza*) es donde me surgen las siguientes dudas: 
Supongo que en cuanto a migración, las relaciones (que en este caso es de **uno a muchos** está bien contemplado, no creo que esté mal eso) pero ésto es solo por la parte de **migración**. *¿Qué pasa con Eloquent (**ORM**)?* Es decir, a cada **migración** le corresponde un **modelo**.

Voy a poner en este caso uno de los dos modelos (*Clase y Raza*) pues es al fin y al cabo lo mismo, y se le aplicará el mismo método, ya que **ambas** son de relación **1-N**. Pongamos en el ejemplo del **modelo** de **Raza**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Raza extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Si os fijáis, en **la parte del modelo (ORM eloquent)** no indico en ningún momento la relación entre modelo, yo como lo estoy haciendo es a nivel de migración. Pero para el modelo, *a mi entender tal cual lo tengo*, no sabe las relaciones entre los modelos. **Mis dudas son:**

1)**¿Las relaciones entre tablas deben de hacerse tanto a nivel de migración (*como lo tengo hecho*) como a nivel de modelo(*que en mi caso tengo el modelo vacío*)?**

2)Si la respuesta es **sí** que tendría que poner a mis modelos algo como esto? :

```
 public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

3)**¿Por qué tendría que estar en una función y que sentido le busco para el nombre?**

4) **¿Es malo hacer una relación a nivel de migración pero no a nivel de modelo? No entiendo la necesidad de hacerlo doblemente(Migración y modelo)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)¿Las relaciones entre tablas deben de hacerse tanto a nivel de migración (como lo tengo hecho) como a nivel de modelo(que en mi caso tengo el modelo vacío)?**

Las relaciones de las migraciones ayudan a nivel de base de datos, no olvides que la base de datos es muy independiente a lo que suceda en **php**(`laravel`), por **ejemplo** al tratar de eliminar una tupla que tenga tuplas dependiente gracias a una llave foranea, la base de datos nos informara que no se puede eliminar dicha tupla hasta que no tenga mas dependientes.

Hacer la relación a nivel de modelo es para ser manejado en laravel(php), que como dije es independiente de la base de datos y estas relaciones hacen que las consultas con **Eloquent** sean mas sencillas de hacer, es más no es necesario conocer sql para hacer consultas.

**Entonces la respuesta es:** En ninguna de las dos es obligatorio, en las migraciones serian para que tu base de datos quedara tan completa sea posible y en los modelos para que al momento del desarrollo tu vida sea mas facil. ;)

**2)Si la respuesta es sí, que tendría que poner a mis modelos algo como esto? :**

```
 public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

**Respuesta:** Existen varios metodos para realizar las relaciones:

```
One To One
One To Many
One To Many (Inverse)
Many To Many
Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models
Has One Through
Has Many Through
```

Así que te invito a leer la [documentacion de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) ya que ahi estan explicadas de manera detallada y no creo hacerlo mejor que eso.

**3)¿Por qué tendría que estar en una función y que sentido le busco para el nombre?**

Dependiendo a la relación que exista entre modelos: Si 1 Mundo tiene N Clases, su inversa seria: 1 Clase pertenece a 1 Mundo, Entonces en tus modelos tendrias algo asi:

```
class Mundo extends Model
{
    public function clases() {
       return $this->hasMany(Clase::class); // has many = tiene muchos(as)
       //si lo leemos diria algo asi: 1 Mundo tiene muchas clases
    }
}
class Clase extends Model
{
    public function mundo() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Mundo::class);  //belongs To= pertenece a
       //si lo leemos diria algo asi: 1 clase pertenece a 1 mundo
    }
}
```

Ves lo sencillo del tema.

**Acceso y utilización:**

```
$clase='media';
$mundos=App\Mundo::with(["clases"=>function($query)use($clase){
    $query->where("descripcion",'like','%'.$clase.'%');
}])->where("nombre","ABC")->get();
//Como la relacion es de una a muchos, `clases es un array y es necesario recorrerlos por un foreach`
foreach($mundos as $mundo){
    dump($mundo->nombre);
    foreach($mundo->clases as $clase){
        dump($clase->nombre);
    }
}

$clases=App\Clase::with("mundo")->get();
//Como la relación es de una a una, `mundo es un objeto y se acede como tal`
foreach($clases as $clase){
    dump($clase->mundo->nombre);
    // lo interesante es que puedes acceder a los hermanos de esa clase con:
    dump($clase->mundo->clases);//este deberia se un array
}
```

**4) ¿Es malo hacer una relación a nivel de migración pero no a nivel de modelo? No entiendo la necesidad de hacerlo doblemente(Migración y modelo)**

Creo que ya explique todo y el hacerlo doblemente no es necesario pero si no quiere tener problemas con tus avances o con el mismo sistema, te recomiendo que lo sigas asiendo asi.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la informacion. Me has aclarado bastante todo este tema.

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar, dices que:

> 1 Mundo tiene N Clases y, por otro lado, 1 Mundo tiene N Razas

Bien, en el modelo Mundo deberías de tener la relación respecto a Clases y respecto a Razas. En el modelo de Clases deberías de tener la relación respecto a Mundo y en el modelo de Razas, respecto a Mundo.

Pero, antes de definir estas relaciones en los modelos, debes tener claro que tipo de relación se trata porque todo tiene su contrapartida, si la relación es uno a uno, uno a muchos o de muchos a muchos.

Ejemplo:

Si:

> 1 Mundo tiene N Clases

A) Si una Clase pertenece a un único Mundo, estaría en una relación uno a muchos.

B) Si una Clase perteneciera a muchos Mundos, estarías en una relación muchos a muchos.

Ejemplo, si fuera el caso de la opción (A):

Para una relación de uno a muchos,

El modelo Mundo debería de tener:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mundo extends Model
{
    public function razas() {
       return $this->hasMany(Raza::class);  
    }

}
```

La contrapartida para el modelo Raza, en una relación de uno a muchos, sería:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Raza extends Model
{
    public function mundo() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Mundo::class);  
    }

}
```

Nota el singular o el plural del nombre de las funciones, es importante eso. Ya que como 1 Mundo tiene muchas Razas, la consulta de eloquent que usarás para saber las clases que corresponden al Mundo con id = 1, sería simplemente:

```
Mundo::find(1)->clases;
```

En cuanto a las migraciones:

Para este tipo de relación (uno a muchos), en este caso, la tabla razas debe tener:

```
$table->integer('mundo_id')->unsigned();
```

El campo tiene que llamarse, nombre del modelo de su contrapartida (mundo) concatenado con "_id".

Creo que es una buena práctica, como bien has hecho, definir tus claves foráneas en las migraciones, aunque también podrías especificarlas en las funciones de los modelos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la informacion. Me has aclarado bastante todo este tema.